# Find and Replacement of $ in a config file using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Oh hey,

So I have some xml config files that I want to find a specific Keyword of "$Machine_Name$" in and replace it with the IP Address coming from a database.

So I am able to grab the correct info from the Database, but I am having issues being able to replace specifically the $Machine_Name$ Hook in the XML Config File.

```
<add key="blah" value="soap.tcp://$Machine_Name$:PORT/blah" />
<add key="blah2" value="soap.tcop//$Machine_Name$:PORT/blahblah" />
<add key="blah3" value="soap.tcop//$Machine_Name$:PORT/blahblahblah" />
```

I have about 50+ lines similar to this, that I want to Find and Replace just the $Machine_Name$ Hook.   In this instance I don't think a Get-Content [xml] file.exe.config and doing a node search and replace buys me anything.  I would have to build all of the Strings in Powershell, and if any of them ever change, then I would have to redo my script, where the $Machine_Name$ Hook will always be there.

Anyways,  What I have tried so far that doesn't seem to work:

```
(Get-Content C:\Test\Project.exe.config)  
| ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "$Machine_Name$" , "*"} 
| Set-Content C:\Test\Project.exe.config
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ok Guys, Sorry.... I figured it out....

Because $ is a reserved Character in Powershell, I couldn't just openly replace it. I had to add a \ in from of both the $'s

```
(Get-Content C:\Test\Project.exe.config) 
| ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\$Machine_Name\$', "IP" } 
| Set-Content C:\Test\Project.exe.config
```

Comment: `$` is a special character in PowerShell _and_ Regular Expressions which is what you were doing. Since you are doing a regex replacement you needed to escape the $ with a \.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just doing a literal match and replace, you can use the string `.Replace()` method. It's simpler, and doesn't need a `foreach` if you use the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content` to read it as a single string.

```
(Get-Content C:\Test\Project.exe.config -Raw).Replace('$Machine_Name$','IP') | 
 Set-Content C:\Test\Project.exe.config
```

Comment: Good catch on the pipe.  Fixed.